# How to save every line in file (IN C) in a variable? :)

Tags: c, file, save, line

I need to save every line of text file in c in a variable.
Here's my code

```
int main()
{
    char firstname[100];
    char lastname[100];
    char string_0[256];
    char string[256] = "Vanilla Twilight";
    char string2[256];

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("record.txt","r");

    while(fgets(string_0,256,file) != NULL) 
    {

        fgets(string2, 256, file);
        printf("%s\n", string2);


        if(strcmp(string, string2)==0)
            printf("A match has been found");
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Some lines are stored in the variable and printed on the cmd but some are skipped.

What should I do? When I tried sscanf(), all lines were complete but only the first word of each line is printed. I also tried ffscanf() but isn't working too. In fgets(), words per line are complete, but as I've said, some lines are skipped (even the first line).
I'm just a beginner in programming, so I really need help. :(

Comment: P.S. I need to store it in a variable as I still have something to do with it. :)

Comment: You are skipping the first line because you are not using the content of `string_0`. You are just discarding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're skipping over the check every odd number of lines, as you have two successive `fgets()` calls and only one `strcmp()`. Reduce your code to

```
while(fgets(string_0,256,file) != NULL) 
    {    
        if( ! strcmp(string_0, string2) )
            printf("A match has been found\n");
    }
```

FWIW, `fgets()` reads and stores the trailing newline, which can cause problem is string comparison, you need to take care of that, too.

As a note, you should always check the return value of `fopen()` for success before using the returned pointer.

Comment: Plus also read the remainder of the line if it's longer than 256 characters.

Comment: Thank youuuuuu. I really appreciate it :D. I finally got it working, and I need every line to be saved in *words_per_line[100]. But the problem is that only the last line of the file is saved for every run of while loop. I followed your correction and just added for words_per_line[i]= line i. Sorry if Im bothering you, I just really need to store it in an array of strings. :')